# Selenium automation getting "Out of memory" on bulk records update

Tags: java, selenium, maven

We have developed a maven-based java project and which replacing emails in bulk but after a certain time browser goes to "Out of memory error".
Initially, we were doing it in the Chrome browser but later on, some research used Microsoft Edge due to less memory consumption. In selenium, the script browser navigates 6 or 7 pages.

Running on 12GB of RAM system and eclipse takes normally around 900 MB and MS-Edge taking around 1600 MB
After a certain time program crashes due to browser memory.

[image: This error message shows in chrome browser]

Comment: Have you quitting driver after every test?

Comment: Why can't you try in headless mode?

Comment: Yes quitting on exception and after successfully run.
 Headless not tried yet due to seeing console of bulk data traking. 
Could you please give headless code with Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to play with java xmx and xms parameters with big values when launch your java app to solve the issue.
To have a deeper analysis, you could use a tool like Jprofiler or Arthas to probe your application stack.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try with your solution. Right now i have following values set:
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m

Now Using a 64-bit Eclipse with a 64-bit JVM helps you to start up eclipse with much larger memory. (I am starting with -Xms1024m -Xmx4000m) then will confirm.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments try it in `headless` mode. This is not an solution but I cannot put entire this thing as comment.

**Maven dependency**: Use selenium 4

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
</dependency>
```

**Launch in `headless` mode**:

```
    /*Edge options*/
    EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
    edgeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

   /* Initialize and adding chrome options to the driver. */
    driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

I am not sure you are using `cucumber` or `TestNG` if you are not quitting the browser at end of the test then please `quit` it.

```
driver.quit();
```

If you are still seeing issue then run below command after `driver.quit();`

```
driver.quit();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM EdgeDriver.exe");
```

> Running on 12GB of RAM system and eclipse takes normally around 900
> MB and MS-Edge taking around 1600 MB After a certain time program
> crashes due to browser memory.

Close the any other edge browsers which was opened manually before run.

Comment: Have you tried this solution?